# ReactNative Cannot update a component from inside the function body of a > different component

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-drawer

My **HomeHeader** component is like this:

```js
import React from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet, Text, Image } from "react-native";
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome5";

export default function HomeHeader({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.home_header}>
      <Icon
        style={styles.menu}
        name="bars"
        size={30}
        color="white"
        onPress={navigation.toggleDrawer()}
      />

      <Image
        style={styles.header_logo}
        source={require("../assets/logo.png")}
      />
      <Text>Hello</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

And am using it in my **Home** screen like this:

```js
return (
  <View>
    <HomeHeader navigation={navigation} />
  </View>
)
```

But am receiving this error message:

> Warning: Cannot update a component from inside the function body of a
> different component.

What am trying to do is, I have separated out the header section of my HOME screen into a separate component called HomeHeader. And in this component, am attaching the event handler to toggle the opening/closing of the DrawerNavigation (left side drawer menu)

If I create a Button in my HOME screen and add the event handler to toggle the drawer, it works fine. But the issue happens only if I try this from inside my HomeHeader component.

Btw, am using ReactNavigation v5 and I even tried this method: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/connecting-navigation-prop/

No luck so far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change `onPress={ navigation.toggleDrawer() }` to  `onPress={ ()=> navigation.toggleDrawer() }`

You can read more about this in [here](https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/02/26/react-v16.13.0.html)